# Why does my function go into infinite loop sometimes?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, infinite-loop, free

I have the following code. It is running fine. But sometimes the del and ins functions are going into infinite loop but sometimes working fine. The readt function is working fine, still I have included it for your reference. What is the problem with my del and ins? Is there any memory leak?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<unistd.h>

struct node
{   int info;
    struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node m;

m *search(int,m*);
m *del(int,m*);
m *ins(int,int,m*);
int posof(int,m*);


int readt(m *t_c,char path[])
{   int t,szt=0;
    FILE *tfile;
    char ch;
    char filename[]="/temp.txt";
    strcat(path,filename);
    tfile=fopen(path,"r");
    if(tfile==NULL)
        exit(0);
    fseek(tfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    szt = ftell(tfile);
    fseek(tfile,0,SEEK_SET);
    if(szt!=0)
    {   while(1)
        {   fscanf(tfile,"%d%c",&t,&ch);
            t_c->info=t;
            t_c->link=(m*)malloc(sizeof(m));
            t_c=t_c->link;
            if(ch==';')
                break;
        }       
    }
    t_c->link=NULL;
    //free(t_c);
    fclose(tfile);
    return 0;
}

m *search(int Noftarget,m *t_c)
{   int i,p1,p2;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {   p1=(1+rand()%(Noftarget));
        p2=(1+rand()%(Noftarget));
        t_c=del(p1,t_c);
        t_c=ins(p1,p2,t_c);
        break;
    }
    return t_c;
}

m *del(int target,m *t_h)
{   m *t_c;
    int j=1,i;
    t_c=t_h;
    i=posof(target,t_h);
    if(i==1)
    {   t_c=t_c->link;
        t_h=t_c;
    }
    else
    {   while(j<i-1)
        {   t_c=t_c->link;
            j++;
        }
        t_c->link=t_c->link->link;
    }
    return t_h;
}

m *ins(int target,int position,m *t_h)
{   int j=0;
    m *swaptarget,*t_c;
    t_c=t_h;
    swaptarget=(m*)malloc(sizeof(m));
    swaptarget->info=target;
    if(position==1)
    {   swaptarget->link=t_c;
        t_h=swaptarget;
    }
    else
    {   while(j<position-2)
        {   t_c=t_c->link;
            j++;
        }
        swaptarget->link=t_c->link;
        t_c->link=swaptarget;
    }
    free(swaptarget);
    return t_h;
}

int posof(int p1,m *t_c)
{   int i=1,a=0;
    while(t_c->link!=NULL)
    {   if(p1==t_c->info)
        {   a=i;
            break;
        }
        t_c=t_c->link;
        i++;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{   int Noftarget=8,j,r=1,count=0,noi,szd_n=0,i=0,sz;
    char cwd[200];
    m *t_h;
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    t_h=(m*)malloc(sizeof(m));
    readt(t_h,cwd);
    t_h=search(Noftarget,t_h);
    free(t_h);
    return 0;
}
```

and the content of temp file is:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;

Comment: Not checking well, `readt` wil put a freed pointer in the linked list and it may be bad.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?????

Comment: yes I have tried debugging. And by debugging I am able to tell that it is not creating problem in readt function, rather creating problem in del and/or ins function. I disabled ins and tried only with del and disabled all the operations there, only keeping upto posof function. But in some cases, it is not even performing posof.

Comment: In `readt()` you have a peculiar way of looping around `fscanf`. Instead of checking to see if there are "any bytes" in the file and hoping the input works as you expect, you should use the return value from `fscanf` to control the loop, as well as the "early exit". The function also frees `t_c` but `main` then frees it again as `t_h`. Horrible.

Comment: Am I not supposed to free each time, I am using a malloc?

Comment: @WeatherVane `t_c` may be updated in `readt`, so the double-free need not occur.

Comment: Sorry: edit: yes you do manipulate `t_c` but are you sure you are not deleting a link in your list? Why do you set `t_c->link = NULL` and then immediately `free(t_c)`?

Comment: How to delete a link? By free(t_c)? No. I have checked it.

Comment: The previous struct still points to one you have freed. It might work "if you are lucky". But even then the last link (which is in memory you have no business accessing, and may have been reallocated) has no data in it.

Comment: and check return value of `malloc()` ... bte don't cast `malloc()`

Comment: Ok, I have removed the free from readt function and running the code several times with a print of t_c->info. It is giving correct output (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8). Although I have tried the same with the free for several times and it also gave correct for each time.

Comment: Actually I added the free in readt as splint was showing memory leak there. Why splint is showing memory leak?

Comment: @LSG, `splint` is a *source* analyzer, and its usefulness is pretty limited for non-annotated source.  It guesses that function `readt()` obtains ownership of the pointer passed to it via parameter `t_c`, and therefore has the responsibility of freeing it.  But that guess is wrong.  I suggest instead using a runtime analyzer such as valgrind to check *actual* memory usage.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger. I have used valgrind and found the memory leaks and removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program contains memory leaks. Memory is allocating iteratively inside the while loop but only one pointer is removing at the end. Need to remove all allocations. And there is no need to free any pointer at the ins function rather del function needs the free operation of deleted pointer. The modified code is here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<unistd.h>

struct node
{   int info;
    struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node m;

m *search(int,m*);
m *del(int,m*);
m *ins(int,int,m*);
int posof(int,m*);


int readt(m *t_c,char path[])
{   int t,szt=0;
    FILE *tfile;
    char ch;
    char filename[]="/temp.txt";
    strcat(path,filename);
    tfile=fopen(path,"r");
    if(tfile==NULL)
        exit(0);
    fseek(tfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    szt = ftell(tfile);
    fseek(tfile,0,SEEK_SET);
    if(szt!=0)
    {   while(1)
        {   fscanf(tfile,"%d%c",&t,&ch);
            t_c->info=t;
            t_c->link=(m*)malloc(sizeof(m));
            //printf("%d ",t_c->info);
            t_c=t_c->link;
            if(ch==';')
                break;
        }       
    }
    t_c->link=NULL;
    //free(t_c);
    fclose(tfile);
    return 0;
}
m *search(int Noftarget,m *t_c)
{   int i,p1,p2;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {   p1=(1+rand()%(Noftarget));
        p2=(1+rand()%(Noftarget));
        t_c=del(p1,t_c);
        t_c=ins(p1,p2,t_c);
        break;
    }
    return t_c;
}
m *del(int target,m *t_h)
{   m *t_c;
    int j=1,i;
    t_c=t_h;
    i=posof(target,t_h);
    if(i==1)
    {   free(t_c);
        t_c=t_c->link;
        t_h=t_c;
    }
    else
    {   while(j<i-1)
        {   t_c=t_c->link;
            j++;
        }
        free(t_c->link);
        t_c->link=t_c->link->link;
    }
    return t_h;
}
m *ins(int target,int position,m *t_h)
{   int j=0;
    m *swaptarget,*t_c;
    t_c=t_h;
    swaptarget=(m*)malloc(sizeof(m));
    swaptarget->info=target;
    if(position==1)
    {   swaptarget->link=t_c;
        t_h=swaptarget;
    }
    else
    {   while(j<position-2)
        {   t_c=t_c->link;
            j++;
        }
        swaptarget->link=t_c->link;
        t_c->link=swaptarget;
    }
    return t_h;
}
int posof(int p1,m *t_c)
{   int i=1,a=0;
    while(t_c->link!=NULL)
    {   if(p1==t_c->info)
        {   a=i;
            break;
        }
        t_c=t_c->link;
        i++;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{   int Noftarget=7,j,r=1,count=0,noi,szd_n=0,i=0,sz;
    char cwd[200];
    m *t_h;
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    t_h=(m*)malloc(sizeof(m));
    readt(t_h,cwd);
    print_tsp(t_h);
    t_h=search(Noftarget,t_h);
    print_tsp(t_h);
    while(t_h!=NULL)
    {   free(t_h);
        t_h=t_h->link;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is checked by valgrind and does not have any memory leak.